# Application deployment to Apple Store Automatically

Tags: ios, deployment, mobile-application

I need to deploy an ios application using web service or API. Has Apple Store got a web service or API to connect to store automatically?

Thanks for your helps and recommendations.

**UPDATE:**

My customer is a very big company in Turkey and they have a lot of operational processes. Actually we are trying to automate all manual operations like below.

They have an ios application and They want to submit new releases of application  to Apple Store automatically. Is that possible?

Sorry for my English if I don't express oneself clearly.

Comment: to get what data and for what purpose exactly? your question is unclear and broad currently...

Comment: Have a look at [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/)

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple does not have any kind of automated system to deploy an app on their app store. Such a system could be abused by spamming it with many entries and apple as far as I know actually has developers look through each application line by line in order to determine if the app follows their guidelines. Apple has a very tight grasp on their app store.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing from apple side and I wouldn't expect them introduce anything in the closest future. We have been successfully using Fastlane for a while now for exactly those purposes and it seems to work fine. It creates the app, provisioning profile, upload package and much more. Basically everything related to appStore deployment. Of course you need a working mac machine as it won't run on liunux/windows server

Official website: [FastLane](https://fastlane.tools/)

Other potential solution (that w have been forced to introduce against Play Store) is Selenium/CodedUI automated UI Tests to simulate user manual input. Not very reliable though.